# Google cloud sql: What are the number of applications for each instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-sql

I'm using D1 size of google cloud sql instance and billing is enabled.Till some days before i can only create 3 authorized application with that instance. When i tried to create more than three it will show 'You have reached the maximum number of authorized applications'. But now i can create more than 5 applications. Then what is the actual number of authorized application that can connect to a single instance.

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing there was a change June 12.

Comment: @ta.speot.is On their official site, they mentioned as ' You are limited to a certain number of applications per instance, depending on your instance size.'

Comment: It is totally depend on google's policy. It had been only allow 1 authorized application instnace for D1 before and 3 for D2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no longer a limit.  It sounds like there are some remnants of the limit in the console still.  We'll fix that up.